# Plupload - Upload multiple image simultaneously

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, plupload

I have use plupload image upload plugin in my website(asp.net), I have modify plupload plug-in for upload multiple image simultaneously.

Old Code

```
function t() {
        var x, y = 0, w;
        if (this.state == g.STARTED) {
            for (w = 0; w < u.length; w++) {                    
                if (!x && u[w].status == g.QUEUED) {
                    x = u[w];
                    x.status = g.UPLOADING;
                    if (this.trigger("BeforeUpload", x)) {
                        this.trigger("UploadFile", x)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    y++
                }                    
            }
            if (y == u.length) {
                this.stop();
                this.trigger("UploadComplete", u)
            }
        }
    }
```

i have modify `if (!x && u[w].status == g.QUEUED) {` to `if (u[w].status == g.QUEUED) {` (remove `!x` from if condition) and it is uploading multiple image simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for selecting multiple files for upload.

```
<input id="File1" multiple="multiple" type="file" />
```

Comment: I am able to upload multiple file but i want to upload multiple file simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

"Plupload was not written with simultaneous uploads in mind" from one of the plupload maintainers (Davit); they are considering it in plupload 2. you can follow up the discussion [here](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=3423) For now if you want to  do the uploading all with one click..you can in the  plupload parameters set multi_selection to true as:

```
        $("#uploaderdiv").plupload({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight',
        multi_selection: true,
        multipart: true,
```

Hope this helps...